# Помогите сделать парсер txt ответа из itunes store

Tags: java, парсер

Есть апи для запросов: https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searchexamples
в приложении нужно вытащить из ответа по запросу, например https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=imagine+dragons, название группы, альбом, трек и иконку альбома для каждой песни. Я новичек в этом деле и уже 2 дня пытаюсь сделать, но информации не могу найти которая может мне помочь. Пожалуйста помогите!

Comment: можно еще чисто взять и вручную искать значения с помощью обычных функций string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ответ приходит обычный JSON, можно использовать Jackson или GSON для парсинга.
Материала море, даже не знаю что выбрать для ответа https://habr.com/company/luxoft/blog/280782/